# Python dividing numbers

Tags: python, math

I need to get 2.66666666666666667 in Python. `8.0/3.0` This gets me 2.66666666666666665
But i want 2.66666666666666667
When i do this `8.0/3.0` in C# i get 2.66666666666666667
It´s like it´s being rounded without my say so.

Comment: Welcome to the programming world: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: And http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: It may have to do with float vs double and their precision.

Comment: Tell us _why_ you need to get 2.66..67. That still isn't the mathematically correct answer, so why isn't 2.66..65 close enough?

Comment: Yeah i didn't realize that if i would round(8.0/3.0,2) i would get 2,67 which is the number i wanted but i wanted to get that number because my calculator and c# gave me that number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from decimal import *
print(Decimal(8.0) / Decimal(3.0))
```

In referenced link it also explains how you can modify the context and adjust the rounding or precision to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Binary floating point sometimes doesn't store things as we base-10-beings want.

You could round or use string formatting to get what you want with floats.

You could probably use the decimal module instead of floating point; it stores numbers, even fractions, in base 10.

Here's something even more precise than what you were asking for:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('8.0') / fractions.Fraction('3.0')
Fraction(8, 3)
```

The fractions module allows you to precisely store rational numbers.